# Getting error about package.json in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, strapi

I'm trying to setup a simple strapi app to use a Postgres database via Docker. When I run `docker-compose up -d`, I get the following error:

`Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'`

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  strapi:
    container_name: strapi
    build: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: postgres
      DATABASE_NAME: strapi
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_USERNAME: strapi
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: strapi
    volumes:
      - ./strapi-app:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: strapi
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: strapi
      POSTGRES_DB: strapi
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `volumes:` in the `strapi` container are hiding everything that's in the Dockerfile, and preventing you from seeing any updates to your `package.json` file.  Delete that block entirely.  (You also shouldn't normally need to set `container_name:`, but this isn't harmful here.)

Comment: Also how would persist strapi data?

Comment: You should be able to persist your application's data in the database.  Ideally your application container shouldn't need persistent state on its own, but stores all of its data in the database.